# Determining if a pdf file has a digital signature in c# without verifying the signature

Tags: c#, file, digital-signature

Is there any way to check if a PDF file has a digital signature?

Comment: What signature format do you use? With CMS / CAdES you could look at the first bytes to see if it is ASN.1. With XMLDsig you can see if it includes the XSD of the digital signature. With PDF you should go to the reserved bytes to the signature. For big files I would recommend to use a detached signature file

Comment: Indeed, the question is too broad at the moment. You could even have your own file format with a signature in a particular place. There's no generic sense of whether a chunk of data includes a signature - it's file-format specific.

Comment: Yes, agree that the question is too broad, I edited.

Comment: Now the question is off-topic. PDF already has digital signature support. You are asking people to recommend a PDF library for C# that can tell you whether the file contains a signature. Have you tried *googling*? Besides, what's the point of simply checking for the signature's existence without validation? Are you going to accept modified documents that still contain the original signature?

Comment: BTW if you google of `PDF C# signature` the very first result is an SO question that links to iTextSharp. There are many other options

Comment: iText has [a signature verification sample](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/clone-inspect-digital-signatures) that loads the signature from a form field

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you need to know is to verify if its signed, you can do:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(documentByteArray)
{
    if (reader.AcroFields.GetSignatureNames().Count > 0)
    {
        // something if its signed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Free Spire.PDF](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html) library provides a functionality to check if a PDF file has digital signature without verifying it. You can get Free Spire.PDF dll from NuGet Package Manager and refer the following code.

```
//Load PDF file
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
pdf.LoadFromFile("Input.pdf");

//Gets the loaded form in the PDF file
PdfFormWidget form = pdf.Form as PdfFormWidget;

//Determine if there is any signature field among the form fields and whether it contains digital signature
for (int i = 0; i < form.FieldsWidget.Count; i++)
{
    var field = form.FieldsWidget[i] as PdfSignatureFieldWidget;
    if (field != null && field.Signature != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This form field has digital signature!");
    }
}
```

Note: I'm an employee of Spire.